# How to extend a function in Javascript for adding new types?

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance

I have an extended PureFunction class like below:

```js
/**
 * @class
 * Represents a pure function.
 * A pure function must have referential transparency.
 * Which means for the same input it always gives the same output.
 */
export default class PureFunction extends Function {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
}
```

When I use the class above for the example below it gives warnings in comments:

```js
/**
 * @template T
 * @param v {T} A value
 * @param f {PureFunction} Mapper function
 * @return {T}
 */
const map = (v, f) => f(v) // Method expression is not of Function type 
map(2, x => x ** 2) // Argument type function(any): any is not assignable to parameter type PureFunction
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: *"It gives warnings"*: what tool gives warnings? Are you using typescript maybe? (then tag...)

Comment: "any" that looks like typescript, not javascript

Comment: I am using webstorm. Oh that any is for JSDoc. It uses TS types.

Comment: Error message is confusing.TypeScript didn't complain Any of those error You gave...Which kind of special tool  you are using?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here with subclassing `Function`?

Comment: I am creating a functional library. So all functions must be in type of PureFunction. So far it doesn't give any error but gives warning.

Comment: out of curiosity... how does the hypothetical `PureFunction` constructor ensure that whatever gets instantiated by it actually is implemented purely functional? In case of passing the implementation as string, is there awareness of that with e.g `super('arg_1', arg_2', .., 'fctBody')` one does practice `eval`. In case of passing and returning a function into the constructor, one actually just practices wrapping, thus making the `super` call useless too. Another Q: Since the constructor does at best return a callable type that was sub classing `Function` what is the benefit of this distinction?

Comment: In order to contribute something to the Q, one might look into [`Symbol.species`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species) in order to prevent the warnings, mentioned by the OP, about the missing function type. Which, in my opinion, makes the concept of sub classing `Function` look even more questionable/obsolete.